# how can i specify dynamic conditions in has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, conditional-statements

```
class Message  
  has_many   :threads,  :class_name=>"Message", :conditions => "`#{Message.table_name}`.conversation_id = #{self.send(:conversation_id)}"  
end  

m = Message.first  
NoMethodError: undefined method `conversation_id' for #<Class:0xc5021dc>
```

I even tried with single quote:

```
class Message  
  has_many   :threads,  :class_name=>"Message", :conditions => '`#{Message.table_name}`.conversation_id = #{self.send(:conversation_id)}'  
end  

m = Message.first  
m.threads
```

This gave me `Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax`
It seems it's not considering the `#{...}` thing while generating the condition sql

i could do it with scopes
    scope :threads, lambda {|conv_id| where(:conversation_id => conv_id) }
and access it Message.where("some condition").threads()
but am looking for a neat association like
    m = Message.find(1000)
    m.threads should give all the conversation threads which it belongs to

Comment: i tried has_many :threads,  :class_name=>"Message", :conditions=>'conversation_id = 1' and i got Unknown column 'message_id'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use dynamic conditions in `has_many`. However, in your particular case it seems you need `primary_key` and `foreign_key` instead:

```
class Message  
  has_many :threads, :class_name=>"Message", :primary_key => 'conversation_id', :foreign_key => 'conversation_id'
end
```

You may also be interested by [one of the gems that adds tree structure to ActiveRecord](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/activerecord_nesting.html).

Comment: thank you . that worked. in fact i thought it only support foreign_key. it is well documented. my mistake :)